# Rewriting URLs in subdirectories with mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've used mod_rewrite to create cleaner URLs for a site located in my document root directory. On moving the site to a subdirectory, the URLs no longer work. How can I alter where the module view the document root in the subdirectory's .htaccess.

If possible, I'd rather not create another .htaccess in the document root or add /subdirectory for each rewrite. I've tried `RewriteBase /sub` but this doesn't seem to come to anything. Any ideas?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^contact$ /contact.html [L]
RewriteRule ^about$ /about.html [L]
RewriteRule ^britishprojects$ /british.html [L]
RewriteRule ^otherprojects$ /european.html [L]
RewriteRule ^video$ /media.html [L]
```

**structure**

```
- /
  - /sub
    - .htaccess
    - index.html etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Rewritebase only works when the substitution parameter is relative. Remove your leading slash on the second arg of RewriteRule.